# Concatenate dynamic date time with text in CSV file

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

**Requirement:** I have an excel file (a CSV) having a column - "Error -today's date & Time" (now()) to be picked every time Windows Task Scheduler batch file is picking this file. The process is saving the file in another system with the column value mentioned above. As it is a daily twice process we need to add the date-time component with static text.

**What has been done so far**: using Concat() or Text() can give text with date/DateTime ("Text 10:00"). The value becomes a static word not changing with date/time change. I close the file and open it after some time it is showing the old value not updated one.

**Query:** Is there a way that every time I open the file it shows the current time concatenated with text?

e.g. 1. At 10:00 AM - "Text 10:00"

```
 2. At 10:05 PM - "Text 22:05"
```

Comment: There are two issues with your setup: 1. in case you'd manage to get the formula working, it'd be updated also when the file is open in the another system, so just showing last open date instead of batch file running. 2. csv files can't store formulas. Workaround: have your original file saved as xlsx and save it as csv after processing.

Comment: Hi @MátéJuhász I will check if we can do the 2nd step in our process. Thanks for the direction. Will get back to you.